# Filter value from a Resultset having UNION statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
   t.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded  
   , t.StatusColumn
   FROM 
   (
    SELECT
    PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded  
    ,STATUSFLAG
         FROM SECTION_TABLE1   --- Status of my section
            WHERE PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded = 50734 
    UNION
    SELECT
    s.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded
    i.STATUSFLAG      --Status of my Item
        FROM SECTION_TABLE s     
            INNER JOIN ITEM_TABLE i ON i.FK_SECTIONKEY  = s.PK_SECTIONKEY  
            WHERE s.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded = 50734 
   ) t
```

**Result i am getting**

[image]

As you can see the UNION will bring 2 records 
1) Section 
2) Item

When this happens i only want to have one result

**What i am expecting**

[image]

I cannot avoid the UNION because it needs to fetch the status from 2 different table for the same key.

What I was thinking is I can write it as a subquery and do some select on top but I do not want to hardcode the logic.

Something like WHEN the STATUS COLUMN has values of 'PARTIAL' AND 'LOCK' it should only fetch the record that is 'PARTIAL' ELSE 'LOCK'.

I even tried CASE BUT it will only look in one column at a time is there a way to look at a resultset and see if this column has multiple values only pick one that is 'PARTIAL'.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure that I've got the target. If this about "get item's status if it exists or section status otherwise" you can just put `LIMIT 1` into your subquery with `UNION`

Comment: What does the UNION's first select return, and what does its second select return?

Comment: But why do you need the union when you're only interseted in 1 row per id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `GROUP BY` and `MAX`:

```
SELECT   t.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded  
       , MAX(t.StatusColumn)
FROM     (
    SELECT     PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded  
             , STATUSFLAG
    FROM       SECTION_TABLE1
    WHERE      PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded = 50734 
    UNION
    SELECT     s.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded
               i.STATUSFLAG
    FROM       SECTION_TABLE s     
    INNER JOIN ITEM_TABLE i 
            ON i.FK_SECTIONKEY = s.PK_SECTIONKEY  
    WHERE      s.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded = 50734 
   ) t
GROUP BY t.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded
```

This will work because `PARTIAL` is greater in alphabetical order than `LOCKED`.

Comment: I forgot to thank you . This query has helped me a lot. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

Now I don't know how many rows there could be per table per id. But if there can be only 1 why don't you just write:

```
SELECT s.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded
 ,case when i.STATUSFLAG is not null then i.STATUSFLAG else s.STATUSFLAG end
FROM SECTION_TABLE s
LEFT JOIN ITEM_TABLE i ON i.FK_SECTIONKEY = s.PK_SECTIONKEY     
WHERE s.PK_DocumentInstanceChapterExpanded=50734
```